# Сплюсовать цифры числа

Tags: c, c++, числа

Допустим есть число 123. Нужно добавить его цифры, то есть 1+2+3 (=6).

Интересует с помощью какой функции в stdio.h это можно сделать, а если нет - то с помощью какой библиотеки?

Comment: Под каждую задачу из лабораторной работы библиотечных функций не напасёшься. Пишите руками.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я так понял, что на входе число, а не строка.

```
int n = 123; // число на входе
int r = 0;
while(n > 0){
    int last = n % 10; // последняя цифра (% - остаток от деления)
    n = n /= 10 // уберем цифру
    r += last;
}
```

В r получим результат.

Comment: в коде есть как минимум две ошибки.

Comment: @KoVadim первая:

     n = n - (n / 10);

вместо

     n /= 10;

а вторая? (Отрицательные числа не берём)

Comment: @KoVadim, а первая - это то, что автор не рассматривает отрицательные числа?

Comment: с отрицательными числами - это хорошее замечание. Я о забытой точке с запятой.

Comment: ошибки признаю. Код написан на коленке с целью демонстрации метода.

Comment: исправьте внесенные новые

Answer (score 0):

Есть древний финт - т.к. все цифры идут подряд во всех кодировках (? я других не встречал во всяком случае), то из символа можно получить цифру от него '0', оно к языку не особо привязано (нам показывали на паскале). Для точной реализации нужно знать в чем у вас строка хранится

И stdio.h это чистый си насколько я помню, уж точно не visual c++

Comment: stdio.h - можно использовать в С++ также, как cstdio

Comment: да я то в курсе, просто отметил что теги не соотвествуют сути вопроса, хотя как оказалось сам не правильно его понял )

Comment: не всякий visual c++ является c++ :) 
(для тех кто в танке - visual c++ -нет такого языка, есть студия. с другой стороны, visual c++ - это может быть как и нативный, так и cli)

Comment: с++, но со своими расширениями типа ATL, которые не понимают другие компиляторы